# bind a method with dynamic arguments

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to bind my `clickHandler` in my constructor for performance reasons and want to pass an index to the click Handler while `render()`.

```
constructor(){
  this.clickHandler = this.clickHandler.bind(this);
}

render(){
  array.map(item,index)=>{
     <input onclick={this.clickHandler} />   //Here i want to pass the item & index as args
  }
}
```

Any suggessions?

Comment: `() => this.clickHandler(item,index)`

Answer (score 2):

create a handler then call it on onClick prop and  pass the index from there.

Example

```
// Creates and returns a function to be called with click event
clickHandler = index => event => {
  console.log(index)
}

<input onClick={this.clickHander(index)} />
```

or

```
clickHandler = (index, event) => {
 // handle here
}

<input onClick={() => this.clickHander(index, event)} />
```

use regular functions if you are using ES5

Answer (score 1):

Create an anonymous function around it, in this way you'll be able to pass arguments to your function

```
     <input onclick={() => this.clickHandler(item,index)} />
```

In case your compiler doesn't support fat arrow syntax, you can

```
     <input onclick={function() {this.clickHandler(item,index)}} />
```

Answer (score 1):

You could potentially use a kind of curried function:

```
    constructor(){
      this.clickHandler = this.clickHandler.bind(this);
    }

    clickHandler(index) {
        return function(e) {
          // do click things
        }.bind(this);
    }

    render(){
      array.map(item,index)=>{
         <input onclick={this.clickHandler(index)} />   //Here i want to pass the item & index as args
      }
}
```

You can't really avoid creating a new function callback for each `index`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. :)

```
render() {
    array.map((item,index) => <input onclick={() => this.clickHandler(item,index)} />)
}
```

Comment: sure i can do this. but if i take this approach i have to call register `clickHandler `method each time i `render()` method gets called. which will impact performance and thats why i want to bind it in `constructor`